# require File::Find: how to use File::Find::name without getting a warning?

Tags: perl, file, find, warnings, require

When I load [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) with [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) like this, how could I modify this script to not get the warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.1;

require File::Find;
File::Find->import('find');

find( {
    wanted     => sub {
        my $file = $File::Find::name;       
        #say $file; 
    },
    no_chdir   => 1,
},
shift );
```

Output:

```
#Name "File::Find::name" used only once: possible typo at ./perl9.pl line 11.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, don't load the file like that. :)

If you do, just add:

```
$File::Find::name if 0;
```

The clean way of doing it is to change `$File::Find::name` to

```
do { no warnings 'once'; $File::Find::name }
```

Comment: This doesn't look beautiful.

Comment: Then don't use a module before loading it.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the `require` with `use`.  That'll fix it.

Generally, the *only* reason to ever use `require` is if you have some specific reason to do deferred module loading at runtime.  Usually, you don't.

If you just don't want to import any symbols from the module, pass an empty list to `use`, like this:

```
use File::Find ();
```

or

```
use File::Find qw();
```

---

**Edit:** If you *do* have a legitimate reason to defer the module loading, and find ikegami's workaround too ugly, you can just disable the warning locally by writing:

```
no warnings 'once';
```

before the statement generating the warning.  This will disable that particular warning for the rest of the innermost enclosing code block.  To find out which warning messages belong in which classes, see [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html).

Comment: I want to load the module only if a condition is true.

Comment: OK, fair enough, that's a legitimate use for `require`. You might've wanted to mention that in your question to begin with.  Anyway, see the edit to my answer above.

Comment: Then only load the code using the module under the same condition.

Comment: Disabling all warnings of one type to silence one warning is ugly because it weakens all the code in scope. Or are you suggesting `do { no warnings 'once'; $File::Find::name }`?  Added the later to my answer.

Comment: @ikegami: That'll work, but if his `wanted` sub really is only a few lines as in his example, I'd just add `no warnings 'once';` at the beginning of it and check carefully that I haven't accidentally misspelled any variable names on those lines. (The "used only once" warning isn't really that useful if you're using `strict 'vars'` anyway, as the OP fortunately is.) But you're certainly right that disabling any warnings, even those of marginal utility, for long sections of code is a bad habit.